# Determine if Thomae's function analog is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I've proven Thomae's function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{q},&\text{if }x=\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q}\text{ in lowest terms, }x\neq0;\\0,&\text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}
$$
is Riemann integrable and integrates to zero. Consider the slight modification
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{p},&\text{if }x=\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q}\text{ in lowest terms, }x\neq0;\\0,&\text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}
$$
I've been trying to prove that this function is Riemann (Darboux) integrable, say, on $[0,1]$, but haven't been able to. Clearly any lower sum $L(f,P)$ for this function is zero, so for some $\epsilon>0$ I've been trying to find a partition $P$ such that $U(f,P)<\epsilon$. Here's the difficulty from what I can see: You have to be particularly careful with how you construct such $P$ on the interval $[0,1/2]$. We have $f(1/n)=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so for each interval $[a_{i-1},a_i]$ in $P$ that contains some $\frac{1}{n}$, we have $\sup_{x\in[a_{i-1},a_i]}f(x)=1$, i.e., you have to control the size of these intervals, or else you have no hope of $U(f,P)<\epsilon$. For the remaining intervals, you have to worry about the fractions $\frac{2}{n}$ in lowest terms, etc. It seems like a complex balancing act, and the smaller the $\epsilon$, the more specific you have to be.

I thought maybe taking the Darboux approach might not be a good way to do it, maybe I should be using Riemann sums. This allows me to choose the points in each interval to evaluate on, but, as far as I know, the corresponding theorem for Riemann sums is that it has to work for any choice of points in an interval of $P$, so this doesn't help much.

Unlike other analogs, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275811/prove-this-function-is-riemann-integrable-similar-to-thomae-s-function), there isn't a way to write this function in terms of Thomae's function. Can you give me some ideas for how to figure this out?

Comment: Thomae's function is usually defined so that $f(x)=\frac1p$ if $x=\frac pq\in\mathbb Q$ in losest terms, with no exception for $x=0=\frac01$, so that $f(0)=1$; thus it's continuous at every irrational and discontinuous at every irrational.

Comment: By a theorem of Lebesgue, a function is Riemann-integrable iff it's bounded and its set of points of discontinuity has Lebesgue measure zero. It follows that your function is Riemann integrable since it's bounded and it's continuous at every irrational point.